# datetime x-axis (timestamp not a string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I started learning python panda.
I want to have the date time on my x-axis, but I have the following Error: TypeError: ('TSLA', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00')) is not a string. 
Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
import datetime as dt  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib import style  
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web  

style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2018, 5, 24)

df1 = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'morningstar', start, end)  

df1['100ma'] = df1['Open'].rolling(window=100).mean() 

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (5, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 1), (5, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)


ax1.plot(df1.index, df1['Close'])  # (x,y)
ax1.plot(df1.index, df1['100ma'])
ax2.bar(df1.index, df1['Volume'])


plt.show()
```

This works:

```
ax1.plot(df1['High'], df1['Close']) #works
```

But I don't have 'access' to the column "Date":

```
ax1.plot(df1['Date'], df1['Close']) # doesn't work
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could show the output as well

Answer (score 0):

df1.index is a tuple

```
t=[str(i[1].date()) for i in df1.index]
ax1.plot(t, df1['Close'])  # (x,y)
ax1.plot(t, df1['100ma'])
ax2.bar(t, df1['Volume'])

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```